# Scenarios where trigger will be more suitable than Process Builder

Tags: trigger, process-builder, bulkification

I would like to know when we should prefer using triggers over Process Builder?

Also is their any bulkification limit for Process Builder?

Also if we can only query 10,000 records in apex, then is trigger a good idea?

Comment: There is an enormous amount of content on this exact comparison, please make an effort to research before posting. Voting to close this.

Answer (score 4):

Process Builder, Workflow Rules, Triggers, and Validation Rules, the essential parts of the save process, each have different uses. Consider them tools that can be used; each has areas in which they excel, and those that they don't.

Validation Rules should be used whenever possible to enforce business rules. They are reasonably inexpensive and don't consume CPU governor limits. Deletion, undeletion, and complex validations may need to be delegated to triggers, however.

Workflow Rules should be used for any of the simple things that workflow rules can do, *except* field updates (Outbound Messaging, Email Alerts, Tasks). They're most efficient in this regard.

Process Builder should be used to perform complex tasks, like updating related parent or children records, invoking Chatter actions, and so on, things that Workflow Rules can't do.

Triggers should be used for anything you can't implement in a VR, PB, for WFR, except notably that field updates to the current object are less expensive to do because of the position of the before insert/update events in the record life cycle, so should be preferred.

PB is pretty abysmal with bulkification, although it is improving. However, it's also currently immune to CPU and memory governor limits, so it is relatively more capable than triggers in some regards, but database writes will take relatively longer using PB rather than triggers.

PB honors the same limits as triggers, so you still can't update more than 10,000 records, query more than 50,000 records, etc. Limits should not be the deciding factor on which way you decide to go. If PB is simply too slow, then triggers are the preferred method.

tl;dr Each of the four tools should be used in tandem to provide the most efficient save process possible. In any typical example, it is likely you'll see two or more of the four tools used on any given object. Using them together effectively will minimize database row locks and maximize save performance.

Comment: "it's also currently immune to CPU and memory governor limits, so it is relatively more capable" - Translation - Will cause all kinds of issue with your code and ISV code if you are not careful, do not know all the quirks, etc as the very next line of code run after an inefficient PB will fail where it worked perfectly before - PB is still a nightmare from an ISV perspective and having to provide all kinds of free support for Salesforce because of it :) - **It is getting better though.....**

Comment: Thanks for the answer @sfdcfox , I have seen a scenario where we were trying to update more than 5000 records with Process Builder, they were getting failed. So is it always a good idea to go for triggers if we are expecting a bulk create/update, which usually happens in the production.

Comment: @Eric Yeah, PB needs to be made to not count against CPU at all (except when it directly calls Apex Code), because developers can't be responsible for the CPU time it uses. There's other limits in place, like the 10 minute transaction limit to keep PB from running away. That or come up with some other solution that absolves developers from their own engine's limitations.